# Puppet Could not find command 'cd'

Tags: linux, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Hi there this part of my code causes an error.

```
   path    => '/bin:/sbin/:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin',
   cwd     => "/var/rapid7installer && unzip ${install_file}",
   creates => '/var/rapid7installer/agent_installer.sh',
   timeout => $timeout,
   require => [
     Package['unzip'],
     File["/var/rapid7installer/${install_file}"],
   ],
 }->
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Profiles::Rapid7agent/Exec[Rapid7 Agent Installation Unzip]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: Could not find command 'cd'
```

I am hoping someone can help me or point me in the right direction. Thank you for looking and your time.

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the entire `exec` resource, please? Currently the post leaves out the (implied) `command` attribute, which is the interesting bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment presented in the question is an incomplete unit, but it appears to be part of the declaration of an `Exec` resource.  In that case, the `cwd` attribute is surely incorrect:

> ```
>   cwd     => "/var/rapid7installer && unzip ${install_file}",
> ```

, and it probably is directly responsible for the issue you observe.  The value of that attribute should be **the name of a directory** that should be the working directory during execution of the exec's command. From context, it appears that that should be just the first part, `/var/rapid7installer`.  The actual command to execute must be conveyed via the `command` attribute, which defaults to the resource title if not given explicitly.

Thus, it appears you want something more like this:

```
exec { 'Rapid7 Agent Installation Unzip':
   command => "unzip ${install_file}",
   path    => '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin',
   cwd     => '/var/rapid7installer',
   creates => '/var/rapid7installer/agent_installer.sh',
   timeout => $timeout,
   require => [
     Package['unzip'],
     File["/var/rapid7installer/${install_file}"],
   ],
}
```